# Write a regular expression that contains three instances of a letter,with exceptions

Tags: regex

How would I write a regular expression that matches strings containing three instances of Y (capital Y) excluding instances of Y that are:

1. Preceded by a:  digit (0-9), + (plus sign) , - (minus sign), " (double quote) or A (capital A), ignoring white space and
2. Followed by a: u, ], Q, T , O, or t.
3. Part of a Date (MAY)

For example:

1. Y    Y   Y     (matches)
2. Y      Y     21-       Yu&RP12BE15  (does not match)
3. Y      Y     21-       Yu&RP12BE15Y  (does match)
4. F19            vs40KETAPY      Y     Y    (does match)
5. Y        25-           15BE22Y      Y   (does match)
6. Y    g^24-     tu&or15BE13Y  F/M  4YO  14MAY GCCN (does not match)
7. Y    g^24-     tu&or15BE13Y  F/M  4YO  14MAY GCCY (does match)

I took a try on regex101 ([click here](https://regex101.com/r/lF4xK1/1)), but I'm not sure how to handle more complex examples.

Comment: Your examples seem wrong, why would `Y Y 21- Yu&RP12BE15Y` match for instance? The 3rd `Y` is followed by `u` and the last one is preceded by `5`, which leaves only 2 valid `Y`. Same goes for `Y 25- 15BE22Y Y` and `Y g^24- tu&or15BE13Y F/M 4YO 14MAY GCCY`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski nice catch.  I've updated my example to more accurately reflect what I'm trying to accomplish.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
//if necessary, loop through all strings
var str = 'F19 vs40KETAPY Y Y';
//remove the matches
var str = str.replace(/\d\s?Y|\+\s?Y|\-\s?Y|\"\s?Y|A\s?Y|Yu|Y\]|YQ|YT|Y0|Yt/g, '');
//check for 3 Y's in the remaining string
if (str.match(/Y/g).length == 3) {
  alert('match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to:

```
not_this|not_that|leave_this|(but_this_is_what_I_want)
```

Translated into a regular expression this ***could*** be:

```
[-+\d\"]Y|Y[u\]QTOt]|(?i)MAY(?i-)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|((?:Y\s*){3})
# -, + or digit before Y or
# Y, followed by u, a ], QTOt or
# if in MAY (case insensitive, this is what (?i) is for
# (*SKIP)(*FAIL) <-- important, do not backtrack
# or Y, followed by whitespaces, captured in a group, three times
```

The following **bold** letters are matched:

***Y Y Y***
Y Y 21- Yu&RP12BE15
Y Y 21- Yu&RP12BE15Y
F19 vs40KETAP**Y Y Y**
Y 25- 15BE22Y Y
Y g^24- tu&or15BE13Y F/M 4YO 14MAY GCCN
Y g^24- tu&or15BE13Y F/M 4YO 14MAY GCCY

A [demo can be found on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qF5eH7/1), this would work in `PHP` for example (you did not specify any programming language). Is this what you were after in the first place?